# Odoo: Values of Many2many with dynamic domain aren't getting saved

Tags: python, odoo-12

I am trying to dynamically change the values of a `many2many` field `products_ids` based on multiple `onchange` functions of other fields (e.g. `brand_id` and `origin_id`).
So far everything is working great and it does show the expected values, but once i hit the save button the values of the `many2many` field disappear

[image]

```
class CustomModifyPrice(models.Model):
    brand_id = fields.Many2many(comodel_name="custom.brand", string="Brand", required=False, )
    origin_id = fields.Many2many(comodel_name="custom.country", string="Origin", required=False, )
    product_ids = fields.Many2many(comodel_name="custom.product", string="Products", readonly=True, )
    search_terms = {}
    product_ids_list = []

    @api.onchange('brand_id')
    def onchange_change_brand(self):
        for rec in self:
            product_brands = []
            for prod_brand in rec.brand_id:
                product_brands.append(prod_brand.id)
            rec.search_terms["product_brands"] = product_brands
            rec.get_products()

    @api.onchange('origin_id')
    def onchange_change_origin(self):
        for rec in self:
            product_origins = []
            for prod_origin in rec.origin_id:
                product_origins.append(prod_origin.id)
            rec.search_terms["product_origins"] = product_origins
            rec.get_products()

    def get_products(self):
        domain = []
        self.product_ids_list = []
        if 'product_brands' in self.search_terms:
            product_brands = self.search_terms['product_brands']
            if product_brands:
                tuple1 = ('brand_id', 'in', product_brands)
                domain.append(tuple1)

        if 'product_origins' in self.search_terms:
            product_origins = self.search_terms['product_origins']
            if product_origins:
                tuple1 = ('country_id', 'in', product_origins)
                domain.append(tuple1)

        if domain:
            products = self.env['custom.product'].search(domain)
            if products.ids:
                for prod in products:
                    self.product_ids_list.append(prod.id)
            self.product_ids = [(6, False, self.product_ids_list)]
```

Comment: Your field is read only, try to use [force_save](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/jco-odoo-patch-1/addons/sale/views/sale_views.xml#L372)

Comment: I totally agree with Kenly.Use force_save=1 in your xml view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `force_save="1"` is placed as an attribute in your field (xml file)